# Dagger 2 Pass Data Into Module After it is Constructed?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Is there a way to pass data into a Dagger 2 Module after it is constructed?
For example, in my app, I have a Dagger 2 ActivityModule in which I set the global variables when the Module is constructed:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    //ActivityModule used for Dagger2
    //Provide other classes/objects with access to certain Activity Components listed within the module

    private SimulatorPresenter presenter;
    private final SimulatorModel model;
    private final ContentResolver contentResolver;
    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final Context context;

    public ActivityModule(HomeScreen homeScreen) {
        this.model = new SimulatorModel();
        this.contentResolver = homeScreen.getContentResolver();
        this.sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(homeScreen);
        this.context = homeScreen;
    }
```

For this module, the SimulatorPresenter global object cannot be passed into the module at the time of construction because it requires another activity to be created.  Therefore, after I create the other activity, is there a way to manually set the SimulatorPresenter object in the activity module using dagger2 or do I need to create an entirely new module/component?

Example of when my module is constructed:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initializeTheme();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder().activityModule(new ActivityModule(this)).build();
        mActivityComponent.inject(this);
```

Comment: Can you explain why your `SimulatorPresenter` requires another activity to be created, and how you're creating it?

Comment: My SimulatorPresenter communicates directly with a different activity.  The SimulatorPresenter is specifically being used to update the UI for that activity.  I'm creating the activity via an intent from my home screen activity (which is the activity that I create the dagger component within).  I was hoping to keep one Dagger Module to make it easier for maintenance but maybe I'm going down the wrong path...

Comment: Never access one activity from another. There is no guarantee that any other activity instance exists at all.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. How does the `Dagger 2` inject the dependencies, when there is no `@Provides` annotated method in the module?

Comment: That's not my full Module, just a snippet of the beginning.   I should've pasted the whole thing.    There are @Provides annotated methods in the module.